# Ajax Loader gif keep showing on scroll bar down after full records loaded

Tags: jquery

I am making a MVC web application, in my app I am loading records using Ajax while user scroll down the page but problem is after full records loaded when user scroll down the page again the ajax loader gif is showing again but disappear. Thats really annoying. Is there any way I can disable the loader gif after full records are loaded. any help would be highly appreciated.
my javascript code is this:

```
 var page = 0;
    var _inCallback = false;
    function loadProducts() {
        if (page > -1 && !_inCallback) {
            _inCallback = true;
            page++;
            $('div#loading').html('<p><img src="/Content/ajax-loader.gif"></p>');
            $.get("/Sort/ALL/" + page, function (data) {
                if (data != '') {
                    $("#productList").append(data);
                }
                else {
                    page = -1;
                }
                _inCallback = false;
                $('div#loading').empty();
            });
        }
    }
    var dcList = true;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            loadProducts();
        }
    });
```

Note: I counted the page and set in to condition, Its also not working.
Need Help. Thanks

Comment: When you say "full records" you mean a successful get?

Comment: you're welcome!, if the question is no longer needed, please delete or answer it. Good luck !

Comment: @NicoSantangelo: Well I thought It should work with counting all pages of with query and set it in the above javascript condition. but its not working. Can you help please. I set the condition e.g if (page > -1 && !_inCallback && page < 24)

Comment: So, you are trying to remove the loader gif, after 24 pages?

Comment: @NicoSantangelo: Yes, I want when after the 24 page loads, it shouldn't  show loader gif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var page = 0;
var _inCallback = false;
  function loadProducts() {
        if (!_inCallback) {
            _inCallback = true;
            page++;
            $('div#loading').html('<p><img src="/Content/ajax-loader.gif"></p>');
            $.get("/Sort/ALL/" + page, function (data) {
                if (data != '') {
                    $("#productList").append(data);
                }
               if( page >= 24 )  {
                     //If we are done, delete the event from window, and delete the loader
                    $(window).off("scroll");
               } else {
                    //The else is only to be sure we wont have another call to the get, it shouldn't be necessary 
                    _inCallback = false;
               }
                $('div#loading').empty();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its working, shouldn't I use page > 24 instead of page >= 24 because starts as page = 0. right?